# How to fetch data from database on fulLcalender

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I am working on it ,and I dont get full data from database of my event, I get only title from my table. The code is given below.

```
 events: JSON.parse(json_events),
```

That`s my code , that only fetches title from database

```
if($type == 'fetch') {
  $events = array();
  $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar");
  while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $e = array();
    $e['id'] = $fetch['id'];

    $e['title'] = $fetch['title'];
    $e['start'] = $fetch['startdate'];
    $e['end'] = $fetch['enddate'];
    $e['dob'] = $fetch['dob'];

    $allday = ($fetch['allDay'] == "true") ? true : false;
    $e['allDay'] = $allday;

    array_push($events, $e);
  }
  echo json_encode($events);
}
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: declare $e = array(); outside of while loop

Comment: so, for example, `echo $events[0]['start'];` gives you `null`?

Comment: print_r($events) once please and display here before echo json_encode($events); code line

Comment: use echo "<pre>"; print_r($fetch); echo "</pre>"; to debug to see if query is returning value or not the use echo "<pre>"; print_r($events); echo "</pre>"; after push.

Comment: when i use all the tricks ,its gives error,,my calender will be not shown ...

Comment: when i use all the tricks ,its gives error,,my calender will be not shown @@ Deep Kakkar